# How to test for Failure Action in Jest using runSaga

Tags: javascript, redux, jestjs

I've tested a successful response, but I'm having trouble with a failing response.

Here's the action:

```js
export function* searchSaga({ searchParams }) {
  try {
    const { text, customers, searchField } = searchParams;
    const results = customers.filter(c => c[searchField] === text);
    yield put({
      type: "CUSTOMER_SEARCH_SUCCESS",
      results
    });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({
      type: "CUSTOMER_SEARCH_FAILURE",
      error
    });
  }
}
```

The test for success passes:

```js
  const initialAction = { type: "SEARCH_CUSTOMERS_START", searchParams };
  it("searches customers with a saga", async () => {
    const dispatched = await recordSaga(searchSaga, initialAction);
    const expectedAction = {
      type: "CUSTOMER_SEARCH_SUCCESS",
      results: [customers[0]]
    };
    expect(dispatched).toContainEqual(expectedAction);
  });
```

When I try to test the failure, however, the error I'm throwing in my mock gets in the way:

```js
it("returns an error on a failure", async () => {
    const error = new Error("uh oh!");
    Array.prototype.filter = jest.fn();
    Array.prototype.filter.mockImplementation(() => throw error);
    const dispatched = await recordSaga(searchSaga, initialAction);
    const expectedAction = { type: "CUSTOMER_SEARCH_FAILURE", error };
    console.log(dispatched);
    expect(dispatched).toContainEqual(expectedAction);
  });
```

The output from this test includes the thrown error, however the console shows that the correct failure action was also dispatched!

```js
 ● Console

    console.log __tests__/CustomerSearch.test.js:48
      [ { type: 'CUSTOMER_SEARCH_FAILURE',
          error:
           Error: uh oh!
               at _callee2$ (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/QMGProzReviews/__tests__/CustomerSearch.test.js:43:19)
               at tryCatch (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/QMGProzReviews/node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
               at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/QMGProzReviews/node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
               at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/QMGProzReviews/node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
               at tryCatch (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/QMGProzReviews/node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
               at invoke (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/QMGProzReviews/node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
               at /Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/QMGProzReviews/node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:11
               at tryCallTwo (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/QMGProzReviews/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
               at doResolve (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/QMGProzReviews/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
               at new Promise (/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/QMGProzReviews/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3) } ]

  ● searchCustomers › returns an error on a failure

    uh oh!

      41 | 
      42 |   it("returns an error on a failure", async () => {
    > 43 |     const error = new Error("uh oh!");
         |                   ^
      44 |     Array.prototype.filter = jest.fn();
      45 |     Array.prototype.filter.mockImplementation(() => throw error);
      46 |     const dispatched = await recordSaga(searchSaga, initialAction);
```

Now, I've tried wrapping this in a try/catch block:

```js
it("returns an error on a failure", async () => {
    const error = new Error("uh oh!");
    Array.prototype.filter = jest.fn();
    Array.prototype.filter.mockImplementation(() => throw error);
    try {
      const dispatched = await recordSaga(searchSaga, initialAction);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(dispatched);
      const expectedAction = { type: "CUSTOMER_SEARCH_FAILURE", error };
      expect(dispatched).toContainEqual(expectedAction);
    }
  });
```

And this does pass, however, it's a false positive. If I change, for instance, the type of the expected action to any nonsense, the test still passes.

How do I make this work?

Edit:
I noticed that the `console.log(dispatched)` was never getting activated in that last passing example. I added a copy of that log statement in the `try` block, and I see that I *am* getting the correct failure action returned.

Playing around with logging, it seems like the error is being thrown and caught in some strange places.

```js
 it("returns an error on a failure", async () => {
    const error = new Error("uh oh!");
    Array.prototype.filter = jest.fn();
    Array.prototype.filter.mockImplementation(() => throw error);
    const expectedAction = { type: "CUSTOMER_SEARCH_FAILURE", error };
    try {
      const dispatched = await recordSaga(searchSaga, initialAction);
      console.log("***DISPATCHED FROM TRY IN TEST***", dispatched);
      expect(dispatched).toContainEqual(expectedAction);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("***ERROR FROM CATCH IN TEST***", e);
    }
  });
```

The above logs the correct dispatched actions from the try block, and then logs the "uh oh" error from the catch block. Removing the last line of the `try` block logs the correct actions from the try block, and that's it, it passes. It passes, of course, because there are no assertions to fail.

So it appears to be the actual assertion that's throwing the error. I can't figure out when the error being thrown and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

How about inlining the error throwing:

```
it("returns an error on a failure", async () => {
    Array.prototype.filter = jest.fn();
    Array.prototype.filter.mockImplementation(() => throw Error("uh oh!"));
    const dispatched = await recordSaga(searchSaga, initialAction);
    const expectedAction = { type: "CUSTOMER_SEARCH_FAILURE", error };
    console.log(dispatched);
    expect(dispatched).toContainEqual(expectedAction);
  });
```

Comment: Well that never defines the `error` variable, so I added `const error = new Error("uh oh!");` to make it run. But then the error is actually thrown, which is the problem I had in the first place (the third snippet in my original question). Your code is nearly identical to that excerpt.